# Slight tweak to custom FnBox code stops it from compiling

Tags: rust

The following code compiles without warning on nightly 1.7.0:

```
trait FnBox {
    fn call_box(self: Box<Self>);
}

impl <F: FnOnce()> FnBox for F {
    fn call_box(self: Box<F>) {
        (*self)()
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

But when I make this slight modification, which I thought meant the exact same thing, I get an error about `FnOnce` being unsized and not movable.

```
trait FnBox {
    fn call_box(self: Box<Self>);
}

impl FnBox for FnOnce() {
    fn call_box(self: Box<FnOnce()>) {
        (*self)();
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Error message:

```
error[E0161]: cannot move a value of type dyn std::ops::FnOnce(): the size of dyn std::ops::FnOnce() cannot be statically determined
 --> src/main.rs:7:9
  |
7 |         (*self)();
  |         ^^^^^^^
```

What is the difference between these two examples, and why are there no problems with the first one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a great difference, actually. In the first piece of code:

```
impl<F: FnOnce()> FnBox for F {
    fn call_box(self: Box<F>) {
        (*self)()
    }
}
```

it is declared that for any type `F` which implements `FnOnce` we implement `FnBox`. `F` is a concrete type, and at each call site `call_box()` method will be monomorphized. The concrete type of `F` at each call site, as well as its size, is known to the compiler, so there are no problems with this definition.

In the second piece of code, however:

```
impl FnBox for FnOnce() {
    fn call_box(self: Box<FnOnce()>) {
        (*self)();
    }
}
```

it is declared that *bare trait object type* implements `FnBox`. However, this implementation is unsound: while `Box<FnOnce()>` is a correct, sized type which is suitable for variables and function arguments, `FnOnce()` by itself is not - it is a bare trait object type and it is unsized, that is, its size is not known to the compiler. This places several restrictions on what you can do with this type, and one of the main restrictions is that you cannot use values of this type *by value*. However, this is exactly what happens in this code: you attempt to dereference `Box<FnOnce()>` to get `FnOnce()`.

Previously by-value `self` methods would meant that the trait is [not object-safe](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html#object-safety), and because `FnOnce::call_once` consumes the implementing instance by value, it wouldn't be object-safe. However, by-value `self` methods do not make the trait object-unsafe since [RFC 817](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/817) got implemented. By-value `self` methods still can't be called on a trait object according to the above reasoning, though.

Comment: good answer. For additional reading I would also refer to the chapter of the Book on [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html) and the [discussion on FnBox](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28796)

Comment: `FnOnce` is object safe, it's just that its method can not be called through an object. *object safety* is equivalent to *trait has an object type*. Without `FnOnce`, `FnMut` couldn't be object safe either.

Comment: @bluss, according to the documentation page a trait is object-safe if it does not require `Self: Sized` (`FnOnce` does not) and if all of its methods are object-safe. A method is object-safe if it either requires `Self: Sized` (`call_once()` does not) or if it neither is generic (`call_once()` is not generic, so that's ok) nor uses `Self`. The latter is the problem, because `call_once()` uses `Self` both implicitly, as a type of `self`, and explicitly, in `Self::Output`, so `call_once()` is not object-safe. Therefore, `FnOnce` is not object safe either.

Comment: @bluss, that's very strange. There probably should be a single source of what is considered object safe and what is not. According to the Rust book, `FnOnce()` is not object safe, as I've shown in the previous comment. I'll probably write about this on reddit or users.rust-lang soon.

Comment: @bluss, I've just reread [this great article](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety) on object safety and indeed, it seems that by-value `self` is not an obstacle for object safety since some change in Rust compiler. And it seems I was wrong about associated types as well - indeed, referencing associated types should not be problematic for object safety even though `Self` is used in their naming because all of the generic types (which includes associated types) are bound to be present in the type of the trait object.